# Is there a user manual for the Specialized bike serial number WSBC618222729N

Tags: mountain-bike

I was just trying to find a manual for my bike the brand is Specialized and all i could see was the serial number WSBC618222729N.  Been searching online but no success, any suggestions?
Cheers

Comment: What do you need help with? Most bicycle parts are from component manufacturers and the same between bike brands, and the rest are usually quite similar between brands.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  I'm afraid serial numbers are rarely useful for anything, and bikes don't normally come with manuals.  You should ask about the specific problems/concerns you have rather than asking about an unknown bike in a general way.

Answer (score 2):

Most bicycle sellers, including Specialized, don't have a manual that is specific to any one bike. The "manual" that sometimes comes with a bike is designed to cover a broad range of bike types so that one document can be used for many types of bikes.

As the comments indicate, the best thing to do is to ask specific questions with pictures.

Here is a link to the web page for the [Specialized Support Center](https://support.specialized.com/home/en)

The page has a list of links for information for the different models of bike Specialized contracts other companies to make with their branding.

Each link takes you to information for that model. For example, the [Allez link](https://support.specialized.com/allez/en) looks like this:
[image]

The [link to "Manuals"](https://extension://apcbkenaegijokcielaijiccehadfolp/data/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.specialized.com%2Fsupport%2Fcollateral%2FSpecialized_Owners_Manual_World.pdf) takes you to a PDF with lots of warnings and generalized instructions for safety, fit, and a section called "Tech" that has generic instructions for a variety of components that let them have one document for many different bikes in many different languages.